# Why in Matlab does breakpoint not get triggered the first time after saving and running an M file?

Tags: matlab

I have noticed a strange and annoying behavior in Matlab. Probably I am just doing something wrong, but when I  make some changes to an M file, save it, and re-run it, my breakpoints are not triggered as expected. If I execute the M file a second time, then the breakpoints are triggered as expected. Why this strange behavior and how do I fix it?

**EDIT:**

Snippet of my Matlab code, as requested:

```
function readCommutingContextData(filename)
fid = fopen(filename);

bufferSize = 5;

format long g
nLines = 0;
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    nLines = nLines + 1;
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);

timestamps  = zeros(nLines,2,'uint64');
coords      = zeros(nLines,3);
features    = zeros(nLines,12);
labels      = cell(nLines,3);
sources      = cell(nLines,1);
fid = fopen(filename);
tline = fgetl(fid);
i = 1;
while ischar(tline)
    tokens = textscan(tline, '%s', 'delimiter', ',');   
    tokens = tokens{1};
    timestamp           = uint64(str2double(tokens{1}));
    gpsTime             = uint64(str2double(tokens{2}));
    latitude            = str2double(tokens{3});
    longitude           = str2double(tokens{4});
    accuracy            = str2double(tokens{5});
    source              = tokens{6};

    ...
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: One possibility is that your code has some interaction with its environment which means that the breakpoint is only hit on the second run.  But without sight of your code, or a minimal snippet which reproduces the problem, you can't expect much more useful help than guesses such as I am making.

Comment: There is some strange behavior when you already are in debug mode. (You can tell by the prompt being "K>>" ) Can you check for that?

Comment: Thanks. I can include my code, but I can assure you it's very independent of the Matlab code I'm running. I've noticed this issue for a long time using many different M files. Also, @bdecaf: No, it occurs when I'm already outside of debug mode (i.e. no "K>>"). It doesn't happen all the time, and I can't seem to find any pattern to when it happens and when it doesn't. Could it have something to do with the fact that I'm remotely accessing the machine where Matlab is running?

Comment: Have you contacted the Mathworks tech support on this one ?  Their existence is one of the reasons for paying for the software. In my experience they frequently solve technical problems.

Comment: I just recalled this post: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/12/11/when-matlab-refreshes-directories/ Maybe you are too quick - or your filesystem requires to use rehash so Matlab gets informed about the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I've observed similar behavior for breakpoints that were set before the file was edited in both R2011a and R2012a.  I believe it is a Matlab bug.

The workaround that I've discovered is to reset (clear/set) at least one breakpoint after editing and saving the file.

Comment: Yes, I've also used this workaround. Do you know if the bug has been reported?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while I was running a code from "command window", and the breakpoints had not been working. After that I surfed and someone else guided me, I used "**clear all**" in front of my calling syntax. Easily remove "**all**" and run again your code and all breakpoints will work.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to handle go to **Breakpoint** Tab and click on the arrow there,first click on the clear all than click set and clear and at last select stop on error option....and your breakpoints starts working well